# match files with regexp and move them

Tags: filenames, pattern-matching

My problem is like this:

The original folder "datasets to optimize" contains 1000s files whose names contain the following pattern:

- variable 2-3 dots or 1 dot with numbers, as in `1.87.184` and `0.35643634`, and sometimes they contain a number in parentheses like `(4)` at the end of number.

How to copy matching files from "datasets to optimize" to "result"?
​

```
~/Documents/optimizer/datasets to optimize #
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 170K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 1.87.184\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 193K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 0.206117(4)\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 199K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 9.58.155\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 187K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 9.61.114\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 181K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 9.6.185\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 212K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 9.64.191\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 171K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 9.66.150\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 231K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 9.72.194\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 241K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 9.73.138\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 176K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 9.83.123\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 179K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 9.83.125\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 181K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 9.83.195\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 176K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 9.85.133\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 218K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 9.85.167\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 195K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 9.86.177\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 178K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 23.92.166(1)\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 210K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 9.89.189\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 218K Nov 11 14:11 'MethodStats 0.2048140\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
```

And output folder "result" has the same but before that is added FW Retest

```
/root/Documents/optimizer/result
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.4M Nov 11 14:14 'FW Retest - MethodStats 1.87.184\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.7M Nov 11 14:15 'FW Retest - MethodStats 0.2048140\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.5M Nov 11 14:15 'FW Retest - MethodStats 0.206117(4)\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.4M Nov 11 14:15 'FW Retest - MethodStats 23.92.166(1)\_vardata\_L6\_probin.txt'
```

how to copy matching files from "datasets to optimize" to "result"?

​

​

Comment: What are the "matching files"? Please [edit] and clarify your question. Also, please use [code block] to format your terminal output and commands to make it clearer and more readable.